# Apache fails after configuration of 2 virtual hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost, apache-2.4

Apache does not restart after having changed the configuration.

Error:
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80

File: /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ServerName sladie.myserver.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/mydomain.com
    ServerName www.mydomain.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

Got this configuration from the [Apache Docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html).

Any idea why this does not work?

Comment: I haven't used Apache for a long time so I can't really help with the question, but I can suggest that I find Nginx to be much faster and the configuration less confusing in situations just like this. If you are able to make the switch, I'd highly recommend looking into it. Good luck and sorry I can't be of more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Debian, you don't need to specify `Listen 80` in your virtualhost, because is declared in

```
/etc/apache2/ports.conf:9:Listen 80
```

Comment: Now that you mention Debian I recognise that I forgot to mention that I am using Ubuntu 14.04. Your answer helped to this case! Cheers, thank's a lot!